# x64 Windows NASM assembly code gives Segmentation Fault on ReadConsole likely due to stack alignment issues

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86-64, nasm

I am writing a prime number generator in Windows x64 assembly. Right now I am stuck at getting user input of a number to generate prime numbers until. This is taken as a string and will be converted into an `int` later.

Currently the code below causes a Segmentation Fault as soon as I enter a character into the console at the ReadConsole function (using `gdb`).

```
bits 64 ; Tell nasm to make 64-bit code
default rel ; Tell nasm to use rip-relative addressing. (Instruction pointer relative).

global main ; Export this

; Import these
extern printf
extern getchar
extern scanf
extern ExitProcess
extern GetStdHandle
extern ReadConsoleA

segment .bss ; uninitialised mutable data.
    ; resb - "reserve byte"
    chartest: resb 1 ; char is 1 bytes
    towhatnumberresponse: resb  4   ; reserve an int with name towhatnumberresponse
    consoleinputhandle: resb 8 ; windows needs this for dumb reasons.
    intstringread: resb 10 ; string read from console
    intstring_as_int: resb 4 ; and converted to int stored here.

segment .data ; initialised read/write data.
    STD_INPUT_HANDLE equ -10
    NULL             equ 0
    printint db "%d", 0xd, 0xa, 0x0 ; 0xd, 0xa is the CRLF line terminator
    printchar db "%c", 0xd, 0xa, 0x0
    printstring db "%s %s, %s, %s", 0xd, 0xa, 0x0
    genorcheck db "Would you like to generate prime numbers (G) or check if a number is prime (C)? ", 0x0
    towhatnumber db "To what number would you like to generate primes to? ", 0x0
    gentowhatnuminput db "%6d", 0x0

segment .text ; Where code is
    ; Function initialisation where we 'allocate' the shadow space required by
    ; Windows. Refer to https://sonictk.github.io/asm_tutorial/#windows:thewindowtothehardware/themicrosoftx64callingconvention/theshadowspace
    push   rbp
    mov    rbp, rsp
    sub    rsp, 32

    lea rcx, [genorcheck] ; print genorcheck
    call printf

    xor rcx, rcx
    call getchar

    cmp rax, 'G' ; no ignoring here pls, compare with rax instead.
    je generate_primes ; jump if equal (rax with 'G')
    cmp rax, 'C'
    je check_prime_num
    ; if none of G or C, then exit
    add rsp, 32
    pop rbp
    ret

generate_primes:
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp
    sub  rsp, 64

    lea rcx, [towhatnumber] ; printf(towhatnumber);
    call printf

    mov rcx, STD_INPUT_HANDLE ; value of -10
    call GetStdHandle

    mov      [consoleinputhandle], QWORD rax ; store handle into consoleinputhandle

    mov rcx, rax ; hConsoleInput
    lea rdx, [intstringread] ; lpBuffer
    mov r8, 9 ; nNumberOfCharsToRead. 1 less than space for a zero
    mov r9, NULL ; lpNumberOfCharsRead: useless
    push NULL ; pInputControl: unneeded.
    call ReadConsoleA ; segfault when input is given after this call.
    ; just refer to this for anything
    ; https://github.com/jacwil/nasm-on-windows/blob/master/01_helloworld/win64/hello64.asm

    cmp rax, 0 ; ReadConsoleA only returns 0 on error, non-zero otherwise
    je error ; just sets return value to 20 and exits.


    lea rcx, [intstringread]
    call printf

    lea rcx, [printstring]
    lea rdx, [intstringread]
    xor rax, rax
    add rsp, 64
    pop rbp,
    ret

check_prime_num:
    jmp exit

exit:
    xor rcx, rcx ; ExitProcess(0) signals success
    call ExitProcess

error:
    mov rcx, 20
    call ExitProcess
```

I think the problem may be due to stack alignment issues or not giving enough stack space but I just can't get my head around this concept at all (despite 4 days of reading theory). I've checked `gcc -S` output of an example C program:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>

char intasstring[11] = {0};
char buf[7] = {0};

void G();
int main(void)
{
    G();
    return 0;
}

void G() {
    printf("To what number? ");
    ReadConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &buf, 6, NULL, NULL);
    printf("%s", intasstring);
}
```

and it used

```
sub    rsp, 80
```

which I tried but didn't change anything. Any help would be appreciated as I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out.

Disassembly at Segfault:

```
0x00007ffc696fe4c5  ? mov    DWORD PTR [r15],eax
0x00007ffc696fe4c8  ? test   r14b,r14b
0x00007ffc696fe4cb  ? je     0x7ffc696fe4de <ReadConsoleA+494>
0x00007ffc696fe4cd  ? shr    eax,1
0x00007ffc696fe4cf  ? mov    DWORD PTR [r15],eax
0x00007ffc696fe4d2  ? test   rbx,rbx
0x00007ffc696fe4d5  ? je     0x7ffc696fe4de <ReadConsoleA+494>
0x00007ffc696fe4d7  ? mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x64]
0x00007ffc696fe4db  ? mov    DWORD PTR [rbx+0xc],eax
0x00007ffc696fe4de  ? cmp    ecx,0x101
```

Register info at this point:

```
rax 0x0000000000000001         rbx 0x0000000000000000
rcx 0x0000000000000000         rdx 0x0000000000000000
rsi 0x0000000000000009         rdi 0x0000000000000011
rbp 0x000000e650dffd08         rsp 0x000000e650dffb38
r8 0x000000e650dff9d0          r9 0x000000e650dffad8
r10 0x0000000000000000         r11 0x0000000000000246
r12 0x00007ff7e7e3300d         r13 0x00000000000001a4
r14 0x0000000000000000         r15 0x0000000000000000
rip 0x00007ffc696fe4c5
```

Comment: Which instruction does it fault on?  GDB should tell you.  Wait a minute, you have a `push NULL` but nothing ever balances that.  Since you're reserving shadow space for callees once per function, you should just store a `0` above the shadow space before a call, like `mov qword [rsp+32], 0` before the call.  Because `push` just moves RSP and writes to the new qword, which will be in the shadow space.

Comment: Hello Mr Cordes,
I have replaced the ```push NULL``` with the ```mov qword [rsp+32], 0``` as you suggested, however it still results in a fault on input into ReadConsoleA. In regards to your first question, do you mean within my program or ReadConsoleA?

Comment: It segfaults on some instruction inside the `ReadConsoleA` DLL function?  Which one, like a load or store using what bad address?  Is that one of the args you passed it?

Comment: Is there a way to stop right before the segfault occurs in gdb or other ways to find the instruction it faults on?

Comment: Under Linux at least, GDB catches the resulting signal, so it's like the faulting instruction *was* a breakpoint.  (Since it faulted, RIP still points at it, and none of its side-effects have happened.)  `disas $rip, +100` or whatever to disassemble that instruction and some later, `info regs` to see what was in registers.  I assume that's possible under Windows, because that's an essential feature for a debugger.

Comment: Ok, so something tried to deref a NULL pointer (in R15) when storing a 32-bit value.  We can see from the later jcc instructions that this is inside `ReadConsoleA` itself, even though your code block doesn't say what function the segfault happened in.  Anyway, that NULL pointer had to come from somewhere, presumably a function arg you passed, because a bug in the args you passed is a lot more likely than a bug in `ReadConsoleA` itself in this version of Windows.  But your asm looks to me like it's passing the same args as your C, so IDK.

Comment: You passed the fifth parameter incorrectly. You also did not declare any unwind codes.

Comment: @RaymondChen could you please explain what unwind codes are and how I passed the fifth parameter incorrectly? Thank you for your help,

Comment: "This section describes [the conventions that one function (the caller) uses to make calls into another function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) (the callee) in x64 code." "Every function that allocates stack space, calls other functions, saves nonvolatile registers, or uses exception handling [must have a prolog whose address limits are described in the unwind data](https://docs.microsoft.com/cpp/build/prolog-and-epilog?view=msvc-170)." The unwind codes are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Also, you are calling `ReadConsoleA` on a misaligned stack, and the `ret` at the end of `generate_primes` returns to garbage.